# How can I zoom Mapview with giving corner locations

Tags: ios, swift, location, mkmapview

I have an array like `[[39.1216, 40.5127],[40.5081, 40.5127],[40.5081, 41.1076],[39.1216, 41.1076]]` this and this locations gives me corner coordinates of a city . `[topleft,topRight,botRight,botLeft]`

When user select a city I want to zoom mapview until corners of `mapview` matches this locations.
I searched but cant find any solution. How can I achieve this ?

I can get center position of this coordinates but How can I calculate `latitudinalMeters` and `longitudinalMeters` according to corners locations?

```
  let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: "calculations", longitudinalMeters: "calculations")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the difference (the *delta*) between your latitudes and longitudes and then use `MKCoordinateSpan` and `MKCoordinateRegion` to set the initial visible region of the map.

```
    let latDelta = topLeft.latitude - bottomRight.latitude
    let lonDelta = topLeft.longitude - bottomRight.longitude
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: fabs(latDelta), longitudeDelta: fabs(lonDelta))
    
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: lake.midCoordinate, span: span)
    
    mapView.region = region
```